# Is there really no way to make an optional dynamic segment in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I tried to add dynamic segment which should be optional for my app, first thing is I didn't know they cannot be optional with the :param syntax, and I started getting a strange non descriptive error out of my templates of all things

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shouldSupercede' of undefined
```

It took me over an hour to realize what's going on and no matter how much I tried to make the param optional with *param and (:param), but I could not.

This is a huge problem. If anyone knows the proper way to do this I'll be very grateful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use nested Resources (Tested with Version 1.8.1):

```
this.resource('profile-root', {
    path:'/profile'
},function(){
      this.resource('profile', {
          path : ':id'
      });
});
```

So when you navigate to „/profile“  it will use this Routes :

- profile-root

  - profile-root.index

And when you navigate to /profile/1:

- profile-root

  - profile

    - profile.index

Answer (score 0):

A nested route will provide you with an optional segment. That's the way it's done in Ember. Mind you, this depends a lot on what you want your app to actually do when it hits the routes in question.

I suggest fully reading the routing guide and following the video in the main ember site to really get a feel for what an ember route is and how it's different from what you might have encountered before.

Simple point in case: Routes are responsible for loading data, and can be used to hold actions, whereas in other frameworks, they're really not.

[ edit ]

Further to this, queryParams or globbing paths (using the splat "*" char) might actually be more inline with what you're trying to do.

Comment: I don't see an example of a nested route being used for optional params in the guide...

Comment: Well it really depends what he's trying to do. To a degree, you could say that all nested params afford an optional route. If he's trying to do globbing, then it's possible by using the route globbing feature. (http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_wildcard-globbing-routes) but if he's talking about providing one route which has another optional one on it, then that's possible with nested routes (put a route under a resource). Basically, this question needs more specificity to be properly answerable.

Comment: it's honestly a huge mess. There is no good way of doing this.

Comment: this is the ember app i'm working on https://github.com/mgenev/GC-StartUp-CMS/tree/master/public/ember

Comment: Heya @mobetta do you still think this is a huge mess? (interested). Also, if you've discovered some interesting things, maybe you could answer your own question here?

Comment: well, it is a mess, I had to switch to canary to pull this off. I can answer about how I did that, I think it'd be valuable indeed. I'll try to get a chance to do that in the next 1-2 days.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks :) If you can update all the open issues and discussion you've started on the ember github and sites with it, it'd be freaking awesome :) but I'm sure you know that. <3